# Changing the value of a checkbox defined in an html file,shown in webbrowser,the webbrowser is defined in a usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls, webbrowser-control

I've been trying to change the value of a checkbox control defined in an html file,this html file is shown in a webbrowser control and the webbrowser itself is defined as a user control in C#
I am willing to set the value of the checkbox control  (defined  in the html file and user control) from the form that contains my usercontrol
The related code in user control:

```
    public bool _checkBoxProperty
    {
        set
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Document != null && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Checkbox1") != null)
            {
                bool s = false;
                string chpro = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Checkbox1").GetAttribute("checked").ToString();
                if (chpro == "false")
                    s = false;
                s = value;
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Checkbox1").SetAttribute("checked", value.ToString());
            }
        }
        get
        {
            if (webBrowser1.Document != null && webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Checkbox1") != null)
            {
                {
                    string bls = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Checkbox1").GetAttribute("checked");
                        return Convert.ToBoolean(bls);
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

this piece of code brings the checkbox property in my form and I can set its value,but when I run the program it resets itself to null,
I've been working on this piece of code for days and I fully appreciate some help :)

Comment: Was my question too vague?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply,set web-browser property `Modifiers` to `Public` in user control:

In your form you have access to web-browser directly:like this:

```
   private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl11.usercontrolbrowser.DocumentText="htmlfile";
        userControl11.usercontrolbrowser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(usercontrolbrowser_DocumentCompleted);
    }

    void usercontrolbrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //get
        userControl11.usercontrolbrowser.Document.GetElementById("Checkbox1").GetAttribute("checked");
        //set
        userControl11.usercontrolbrowser.Document.GetElementById("Checkbox1").SetAttribute("checked",true or false value);
    }
```

And in OOP:

### User control Code

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool _checkBoxProperty
        {
            get
            {
                if (usercontrolbrowser.Document != null)
                {
                    return Convert.ToBoolean(usercontrolbrowser.Document.GetElementById("Checkbox1").GetAttribute("checked"));
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;//error
                }
            }

            set
            {
                if (usercontrolbrowser.Document != null)
                {
                    usercontrolbrowser.Document.GetElementById("Checkbox1").SetAttribute("checked", value.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        public void DocHtml(string dochtml)
        {
            usercontrolbrowser.DocumentText = dochtml;
        }

    }
```

### Form Code

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userControl11.DocHtml("htmlfile");
}

private void getcheckbox()
{
    var getval= userControl11._checkBoxProperty;
    userControl11._checkBoxProperty = false;//set value
}
```